# Can someone please help me auto play my slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make my slider auto play. After hours of trying, I just can't get it. Every time the image auto plays, you have to click the next button in order for it to follow along with the auto play. I'm not very familiar with jQuery.

**My Javascript:**

```
sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".slide > img#1").fadeIn(300);
    startSlider();
});

function startSlider(){

    count = $(".slide > img").size();

    loop = setInterval(function() {

        if (sliderNext > count) {
            sliderNext = 1;
            sliderInt = 1;
        }

        $(".slide > img").fadeOut(300);
        $(".slide > img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

        sliderInt = sliderNext;
        sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;

    }, 3000)

}
```

**My CSS:**

```
.slide
{
top: 0;
opacity: 0;
width: 745px;
height: 420px;
display: block;
position: absolute;

transform: scale(0);

transition: all .7s 
}

.slide img 
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 6px;
border: 1px solid #95ca1a;
}

.nav label
{
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
display: none;
position: absolute;

opacity: 0;
z-index: 9;
cursor: pointer;

transition: opacity .2s;

color: #FFF;
font-size: 156pt;
text-align: center;
line-height: 380px;
font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label 
{
opacity: 0.5; 
}

.nav label:hover 
{
 opacity: 1; 
}

.nav .next {
 right: 0;
}

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide 
{
opacity: 1;

transform: scale(1);

transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label 
{
display: block;
border-radius: 6px; 
}
```

Comment: Where is your html? Paste it.

Comment: Just looking at the jQuery and the code you wrote, you never want to have an element ID starting with a number, let-alone, only having a number as an id.

Comment: @C.S. `numbered ID elements` are perfectly valid in [tag:HTML5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a few things, not perfect code I wrote but it gets the job done.

From your code and css, I can only assume you are trying to [build a slideshow like this](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/UcfKf/)

- I renamed how you should create element id's like this: `<img id="slide_1"`...
- I removed opacity from the css styling
- jQuery code looks like this:

  ```
  (function (){
      var count = $(".slide > img").length;
      var current = 1;
      var sliderNext = 2;

      $("img[id^='slide_']").fadeOut(0);
      $("#slide_" + current).fadeIn(300);
      var loop = setInterval(function() {
          $("#slide_" + current).fadeOut(300);
          $("#slide_" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);
          (sliderNext >= count) ? sliderNext = 1 : sliderNext++;
          (current >= count) ? current = 1 : current++;
      }, 3000)
  })()
  ```

Comment: Have you tested your link?

Comment: Only on chrome, havent had time to cross-check other browsers

Comment: in the stylesheet, you might want to make 
transform: scale(1);

I'm only trying to guess what the user is trying to do, there has never been any html nor explanation